# MongoDB Climb Hierarchy up Aggregation

Tags: mongodb

i found a very old project which us using a MongoDB database. Unfortunately I do not get further with a query....

The following case:

We have a document called "folders"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "Children" : {
        "Files" : [
            ObjectId("7"),
            ObjectId("8")
        ],
        "Folders" : [
            ObjectId("2"),
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
    "Children" : {
        "Folders" : [
            ObjectId("3"),
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
    "Children" : {
        "Folders" : [
            ObjectId("4"),
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4"),
    "Children" : {
        "Folders" : []
    }
},
```

This is to represent a folder structure:

Folder 1 -> Folder 2 -> Folder 3 -> Folder 4

I now want a query where the id matches to the "folder 4" and the query should go up the hierarchy and pick out the parent folders 1, 2 & 3.

The problem: but folder 4 only shows up in the "Children.Folders" list of Order 3. Folder 3 shows up in the list of folder 2 and so on.

How to make such a query that finds the searched folder + all parent folders?

Comment: Take a look at [$graphLookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)

Comment: Thank you Joe. I know that graphLookup is the right way but i find some MongoDB queries are so difficult to solve. SQL Queries seems like a joke in compare to them. I spend hours to find a good example without success.

Do you maybe know an example or an website explaining a different situation where i can have an example?